# passing object of a class to another class in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working with google app engine,
I have 2 classes namely A and B and one db model say DB,
I have processed object of DB model in class A, and i want
to send the same object in class B, How can i do this?
Here is my code,

```
class Candidate(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    lastname = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.StringProperty()
    mobno = db.StringProperty()

class A(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        currCandidate = Candidate(key_name=self.request.get('email'))
        currCandidate.name = self.request.get('name')
        currCandidate.lastname=self.request.get('lname')
        currCandidate.email=self.request.get('email')
        currCandidate.mobno=self.request.get('mobno')

class B(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # currCandidate
        # want to access currCandidate object here,
        # currCandidate is from class A
```

I want to access the currCandidate object from class B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'A' handler is a POST, and gets a Candidate object via keyname, which is the email request parameter. Can you not use the same mechanism for the 'B' handler? This is a GET so you will need to pass the email in as a URL parameter. For example https://yourapp.appspot.com/b?email=someemail@domain.com.

You can then pick it up again with the same code you are using in the POST - currCandidate = Candidate(key_name=self.request.get('email')).

Answer (score 0):

since you are creating a web app,you can store the object in session variable and access it in other class.In `java` this is done by `serializing` the object and storing it in session variable

Comment: the logic should to same,i.e.,to store object in session.Just find how how to do it in python.